# Including a button in a WTableView

Tags: c++, wt

I'm working on a Wt-based gui, and struggling with something that feels like it should be very simple:

The gui displays 'events'. In our project we have a model (`ActiveEventsModel`, based on `WStandardItemModel`) and a view, (`ActiveEventsView`, based on `WTableView`). Currently the view simply shows some text corresponding to various properties of the 'events'. The aim is to add an additional column to the table, contain a button (for example, a `WPushButton`) which allows the user to "acknowledge" the event shown in that row (in context, this essentially translates to *dismissing* the event - i.e. each event has a button, and clicking the button will remove that event from the model).

I searched online and found [this](https://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/boards/2/topics/10595) discussion on the Wt-forum, which contains some guidance on putting a button in (derive from `WAbstractItemDelegate` and use `setItemDelegateForColumn`) and a code example for creating a button in an item delegate. After some minor changes for Wt-4.0 compatibility I now have my button in the table.

I've defined a very simple class, `EventDelegate`, derived from `WAbstractItemDelegate`:

header:

```
#include <Ui/WebToolkit.h> //convenience header containing all of the Wt elements we use

class EventDelegate : public Wt::WAbstractItemDelegate
{
public:
  EventDelegate();

  std::unique_ptr<Wt::WWidget> update(Wt::WWidget *widget, const Wt::WModelIndex &index,
                                      Wt::WFlags<Wt::ViewItemRenderFlag> flags) override;

  void acknowledge(Wt::WModelIndex &index);
};
```

source:

```
#include <Ui/EventDelegate.h>

EventDelegate::EventDelegate()
: WAbstractItemDelegate()
{
}

std::unique_ptr<Wt::WWidget> EventDelegate::update(Wt::WWidget *widget, const Wt::WModelIndex &index,
                                                   Wt::WFlags<Wt::ViewItemRenderFlag> flags)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Wt::WWidget> w = std::make_unique<Wt::WPushButton>("acknowledge");

    Wt::WPushButton *button = dynamic_cast<Wt::WPushButton*>(w.get());

    button->clicked().connect(std::bind(&EventDelegate::acknowledge,this,index));

    return w;
}

void EventDelegate::acknowledge(Wt::WModelIndex &index) {
  //how do I interact with the model?
}
```

This seemed promising at first, but I just can't figure out how to actually make the button *do* anything to the model. I thought maybe I need to override [WAbstractItemDelegate::setModelData](https://webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/classWt_1_1WAbstractItemDelegate.html#ad468f58187cf617ba5d52218815e8382), but for that I need the model, which the ItemDelegate doesn't seem to know anything about.

I *do* have the ModelIndex, and the ModelIndex knows which Model it belongs to - but will only give me it as `const`, which is no use to me because `setModelData` needs to alter it.

Should I just be giving the Model to the Delegate directly, for example as a constructor parameter? That seems an easy solution but feels very inelegant. Or am I just barking up the wrong tree entirely with how I'm trying to do this? I'm extremely new to Wt (and my colleagues only a little less so - this is a relatively new project and the first in our company that's used Wt) so that's very possible.

(I've not included a whole mcve because I'm pretty sure that what I'm missing here is *conceptual*. I can add one later if people feel it's really necessary to answer the question)

Comment: An MRE is not needed, although it helps for people that want to quickly experiment with the code, specially those not accustomed to Wt.